# How can i make this animation stop after completion in Jetpack Compose or not be infinite

Tags: kotlin, animation, android-jetpack-compose

```
@Composable
fun Gojo(
maxWidth:Dp,
maxHeight:Dp,) 
{
    val resource: Painter
    val modifier: Modifier
    val gojoSize = 200.dp
    val infiniteTransition = rememberInfiniteTransition()
    val posistionState = infiniteTransition.animateFloat(
        initialValue = 0f,
        targetValue = 1f,
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(
                durationMillis = 1000,
                easing = LinearEasing
            ),
            repeatMode=RepeatMode.Reverse
        )
    )
    if(posistionState.value<=0.1f) {
        modifier = Modifier.offset(
            x = -140.dp,
            y = maxHeight * 0.75f,
        ).rotate(50.0F)
    }
    else if(posistionState.value<=0.2f){
        modifier = Modifier.offset(
            x = -100.dp,
            y = maxHeight * 0.75f,
        ).rotate(50.0F)
    }
    else if(posistionState.value<=0.25f){
        modifier = Modifier.offset(
            x = -100.dp,
            y = maxHeight * 0.75f,
        ).rotate(0.0F)
    }
    else if(posistionState.value<=0.3f){
        modifier = Modifier.offset(
            x = -100.dp+(maxWidth*posistionState.value),
            y = maxHeight * 0.75f,
        ).rotate(50.0F)
    }
    else{
        modifier = Modifier.offset(
            x = maxWidth * 0.25f,
            y = maxHeight * 0.75f,
        )
    }

    resource=painterResource(R.drawable.gojo)
    Image(modifier=modifier.width(gojoSize).height(gojoSize),painter = resource, contentDescription ="gojo sama")
}
```

Comment: Please, apply some indentation to your code.

Answer (score 0):

you are asking for not to be infinite and using infinite transition? just use animateDpAsState and change size of the image by using the dp values. If you want to start the transition when the item has composed just call a LaunchedEffect (true) {startTransition = true} by remembering the startTransition value as false in the beginning:

```
var startTransition by remember {
    mutableStateOf(false)
}
LaunchedEffect(true){
    startTransition = true
}
val size = animateDpAsState(
    targetValue = if(startTransition == false)
        0.dp 
    else 
        /*Your Desired Value*/
)
// And use size in Image. You can create different animateDpAsState values for width and height.
```